# Laravel custom queue mechanism

Tags: laravel, queue

I have a queue implemented in CodeIgniter that works like this

```
class BaseJob{
  function beforeExecute(){}

  function afterExecute(){}
}

class JobType1 extends BaseJob{
   function execute(){}
}

class JobType2 extends BaseJob{
   function execute(){}
}

function jobConsumer(){
    $message = fetchFromSQS();
    $job = new $message->type;
    $job->beforeExecute();
    $job->execute();
    $job->afterExecute();
}
```

I am migrating it in laravel. What Laravel features can I use to optimize queue handling? SQS is already working great. Do I need to use Laravel queue? I am just planning to run consumer as a Laravel command with SQS doing the queue management.

I need to make sure that afterExecute function is always called even if execute function fails.

Comment: you can use simple `try() catch()` finally()` in the Jobs

Comment: @AbdullaNilam if you do that, you need to throw the exception back to fail the job, so laravel retries it. If you don't re-throw it, the job will succeed when in reality it failed.

Comment: Also you won't be notified by automated tools, and things like pingOnFailure/pingOnSuccess will not work as expected

Answer (score 0):

One solution we are using is Bus batches with the finally method :

```
return Bus::batch($jobs)
            ->name('my batch name')
            ->onQueue('my-queue')
            ->allowFailures()
            ->finally(function (Batch $batch) use ()
            {
                // for whatever you need
            });
```

You can do that with `[$job]` if you have only one job

On individual jobs you can only add a catch callback to run some code when the job fails, but i don't find anything like the finally of the Bus batches.

Comment: SQS is already working great. Do I need to use Laravel queue? I was just planning to run consumer as a Laravel command.

Comment: Well i thought you were fully migrating to laravel, but if you want to keep SQS, you can, however i don't think laravel knows when a SQS job ends. Try the SqsQueue within laravel to see what you can do with it